# bash while loop: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
while [ $counter < 100 ]; do
   echo $counter
   counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

However, when I try to execute this, I get this error:

```
./test: line 4: 100: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In bash, `<` redirects standard input, so you're telling bash to read from the file called `100`, which doesn't exist. Instead use `-lt` for comparing numbers.

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
while [ $counter -lt 100 ]; do
   echo $counter
   counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

Does what you want.

Comment: Could I use double parenthesis for arithmetic evaluations?

Comment: It is recommended to quote all your vars. Also, note that the syntax `(( counter ++ ))` is also valid.

Comment: @Kingamere Not in the while. You could use [[ ]] although it uses the same operators for numeric comparison. And @fedorqui is right, you should be quoting variables when you use them, so `while [ "$counter" -lt 100 ]`, etc. It doesn't make a difference in this specific case, but if you change the script to start `$counter` from a command line argument or user input for example, it would.

Comment: `while (( counter < 100 )); do` is perfectly valid `bash` code.

Comment: For that matter, so is `for ((counter=0; counter<100; counter++)); do ...`

Answer (score 1):

The "less than" operator is `-lt`, not `<`.

`<` will redirect the file contents to the command on the left. That's why you have this error: the file `100` does not exist.